# Bus error with semaphore func semctl() in this code running on Solaris

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, semaphore

This is my first attempt on semaphores and threads. 
I constructed this code from examples and the man pages found on the Net.
I have two doubts with this code.

1. Why do I get a Bus error whenever I try semctl( I know this is the root of the problem because of the debug line 3 does not get printed) and how to prevent it?
2. Why am I not able to acquire a lock on my critical section inspite of removing semctl()?

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define NUM 3
char c='a';
int semId=-1;
struct sembuf lockOperation = { 0, -1, 0};
struct sembuf unlockOperation = { 0, -1, 0};

void* PrintLetter()
{
  int rc;

  rc=semop(semId, &lockOperation, 1);

  if(rc)
    {
      printf("\n Unable to lock\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  printf("%c",c);    //CRITICAL SECTION
  c=c+1;             //CRITICAL SECTION  
  rc = semop(semId, &unlockOperation, 1);
  if(rc)
    {
      printf("\n Unable to unlock\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  pthread_exit(NULL);

}
int main()
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM];

  int rc=1;
  long t;
   printf("debug line 1\n");
  semId = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);
  if( semId == -1)
    {
      printf("\n Error in making the sem\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  printf("debug line 2\n");
  rc = semctl(semId, 0, SETVAL, (int)1); // Comment from here

  if(rc)
    {
      printf("\n Unable to set val to 1\n");
      exit(1);
      }    ////////////////////////////////// till here
   printf("debug line 3\n");


  for(t=0; t<NUM; t++){
    printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintLetter, NULL);
    if (rc){
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
    sleep(3);
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

NOTE: 
I added the following to the code after suggestion:

```
union semun {
  int              val;    /* Value for SETVAL */
  struct semid_ds *buf;    /* Buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
  unsigned short  *array;  /* Array for GETALL, SETALL */
  struct seminfo  *__buf;  /* Buffer for IPC_INFO
                              (Linux specific) */
};
```

Also  added the following:

```
union semun s_u;
s_u.val=1;
```

Changed the semctl line to

```
rc = semctl(semId, 0, SETVAL, s_u);
```

and made all rc checks to:

```
if(rc == -1)
```

semctl() line still does not execute sucessfully.
The errno now states :
Permission Denied

**UPDATE**: I am able to get rid off the "Permission Denied" error using the following change:

```
semId = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0660);
```

Now , the new problem is that, I am unable to print "abc" on the console.
The program just prints "a" and hangs. Not sure why.

**Final UPDATE**: 
I messed up in the Unlock code:
i used -1 instead of 1
Here is the new code:

```
struct sembuf unlockOperation = { 0, 1, 0};
```

I thank you all for your help and patience.

Comment: Note: I would like to get my final output as abc

Comment: @Carl: I am using a Solaris machine . I tried the same on a linux machine and got the same'Bus Error'.

Comment: I tried adding the following lines: union semun s_u; s_u.val=1; rc = semctl(semId, 0, SETVAL, s_u); I get the following error: sem.c:42: error: storage size of 's_u' isn't known

Comment: Note: I tried the same code on a Linux machine . The semctl() fails and it exits with the printf("\n Unable to set val to 1\n");

Comment: declare union explicitly, http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/semctl.html

Comment: @tomkaith13 - What's your goal here?  Do you have to use sysV semaphores for an assignment?  You can avoid this aggravation by just using pthreads mutex or even POSIX semaphores.

Comment: @Duck: I wanna get the output as the string "abc" using semaphores as per the assignment. I am yet to try Posix semaphore. 

I constructed this program using the following materials:
http://snap.nlc.dcccd.edu/learn/fuller3/chap12/chap12.html
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzahw/rzahwsemco.htm

Comment: @tomkaith, are you getting an error-code number from the call? Or just the numberless error msg?

Comment: @Alex: 

My new code is this:
if(rc == -1)
    {
      printf("\n Unable to set val to 1\n");
      printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
      }

The message is based on strerror(errno).

Comment: I am able to pull that error off. 
I added the following line:
semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0660);

But I am still unable to get the displayed output as "abc" (each thread printing the character)

Comment: @tomkaith, and what's errno?  I can't identify it from that `strerror`.

Comment: @tomkaith, btw, try to use edits of your question rather than comments to clarify things -- as things stand now a poor soul coming to this Q thread would have to read a bazillion little separated and disconnected pieces to piece things back together, that's **not** the way to optimize your chances of getting good help, you know!

Comment: @Alex: Thank you. I have made edits in the question itself like u suggested. Also, the errno was 13. strerrnr(13) prints " Permission Denied" . But that is solved now due to the new semget statement mentioned above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fourth argument to `semctl` (if present) should be of type `union semun`:

```
union semun {
            int val;
            struct semid_ds *buf;
            unsigned short  *array;
} arg;
```

Maybe passing an `int` there instead is causing alignment problems.

Comment: @Alex: I tried adding the following lines:

 union semun s_u;

 s_u.val=1;

 rc = semctl(semId, 0, SETVAL, s_u);

I get the following error:

sem.c:42: error: storage size of 's_u' isn't known

Comment: @tomkaith, that error message tells you that you have not read (or understood) the manual page, see http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5167/semctl-2?a=view : """type union semun, which must be explicitly declared by the application program.""" -- **explicitly declared by the application**, get it?

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for that. I defined the union now .. But my semctl() still fails with the "Unable to set val to 1" message. Any idea on why I am unable to set this the sem val ?

Comment: See also the POSIX standard (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) which says the same thing.  It is a weirdness imposed on POSIX by a weirdness in the original System V IPC implementation.  I can't think of any other type in POSIX that the user must use but must also define.

Comment: What is the value of 'rc' when the error message is generated.  If it is failing, it should be -1 and errno should tell you more.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks.I kinda expected it be be present in the header files myself since this is my first try at semaphores. I am still unable to get the semctl() to run successfully.

Comment: @ Jonathan: 

The errno says "ERROR: Permission denied". Is this because I dont have root privileges?? I am working on this problem in a University lab machine. I dont think i can get 'su' access

Comment: @tomkaith13 - Type "ipcs -s".  If you see semaphores with your userid then they were created and should show the permissions.

Comment: @Duck: This is the output from the ipcs -s line:

s         53   0          ----------- btk07100       sn

Comment: @tomkaith13: see the man page for semget() (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semget.html) where it says: "Upon creation, the semid_ds data structure associated with the new semaphore identifier is initialized as follows:
* In the operation permissions structure sem_perm.cuid, sem_perm.uid, sem_perm.cgid, and sem_perm.gid shall be set equal to the effective user ID and effective group ID, respectively, of the calling process.
* The low-order 9 bits of sem_perm.mode shall be set equal to the low-order 9 bits of semflg."
I suspect you have zeroes, leading to EPERM.

Comment: And I previously intended to point you to the semctl() information at http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html.  Apologies for the not-as-helpful-as-intended URL.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything else, correct your error handling code.  This is wrong:

```
rc = semop(semId, &lockOperation, 1);

if (rc)
{
    printf("\n Unable to lock\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Semop() and semctl() return -1 on error so it should be something like

```
rc = semctl(semId, 0, SETVAL, (int)1); // Comment from here

if (rc == -1)
{
    perror("SETVAL");
    exit(1);
}
```

This get confusing because the pthread API returns 0 on success and an error number otherwise.  It is easy to get them confused so be careful.

Comment: @Duck:  Thank you for that advice .. I changed my code appropriately. will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass explicit semun union to semctl, rather than rvalue 1.  probably should not matter, but who knows.